# Should I create multiple background images for various sizes of iPhones?

Tags: ios, image

I am trying to add a full-screen background image for different sizes of iPhones as shown below.

I am thinking two options:

(1) I will make 4 images for each of the screen (640x960, 640x1136, 750x1334, 1242x2208)

(2) I will make one image (1242x2208) that has bleeing areas to cover all 4 sizes.

For option (1), since the background image looks the same, is creating 4 images necessary (app size increases)? For option (2), is it a correct way? I have not found anyone talking about this method while researching online.

Which one should I go for? Or better alternative?

[image]

Answer (score 0):

As it is a background image, I suggest making a large image. Make it the same ratio as the small iPhones. Then use either ScaleAspectFit or ScaleAspectFit for the 6+. However, do not scale the image up to the 6+. Good luck!

Comment: Use a PDF! Better for scaling!

Comment: @penatheboss you said `use either ScaleAspectFit or ScaleAspectFit`, both are the same? and what do you mean `do not scale the image up to the 6+"?

Comment: Sorry about the confusion! I meant `ScaleAspectFill` or `ScaleAspectFit`.